# How plot a signal for a crossing Kumo 3 candles later (#barssince)

Tags: pine-script

(Sorry for my english)
I would like to know how I can plot a signal when the chikuspan cross the kumo with a condition : the next 3 candles for the chikuspan must be under the kumo too.

Here for a Long signal:

`````
ichi_lim = input(3 , title="Cross x Bar Limit")

//Kumo Breakout (Long)
LongSpan = (SpanA_Top and source[1] < SpanAA[1] and source > SpanAA)    or (SpanB_Top and source[1] < SpanBB[1] and source > SpanBB) ? 1 : 0
cupSpan = LongSpan  == 1 ? LongSpan : 0
Longcondi = barssince(cupSpan)
Longcondifinal = (cupSpan and Longcondi<=ichi_lim)

plotshape(Longcondifinal , title="Longit", color=green, text="Longit",    location=location.belowbar, style=shape.triangleup, size=size.small, offset=0, transp=0)````
`````

the `Longcondi<=ichilim` doesnt work.
The signal "Longit" work fine as soon the chikuspan cross the kumo. But i have a fake signal when the chikuspan go out then in, then out, then in etc.